# Recurrence relation with prime numbers as coefficients

Tags: prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

I would like to solve the following recurrence relation

\begin{equation}
c_{n} = \left(1-\frac{1}{p_{n}}\right)c_{n-1}+\frac{1}{p_n},
\end{equation}
where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number and $c_0=0$ and $p_1=2$.

Is there a closed form for the solution of this recurrence relation?
How would one go about solving this?

Comment: Why would anybody want to do this?! A joker might ask "give me a closed form for $p_n$, and I'll give you one for $c_n$".

Comment: Appears to yield [A161527](https://oeis.org/A161527) in the numerators.